# Nginx redirect all [http / www / https www] to [https non-www]

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have the following server names that I want to be accessible, on **https**:

```
example.com
test.example.com
api.example.com
api.test.example.com

# And I might add more, all on example.com of course
# ...
```

I want to redirect all `http`, `http://www` and `https://www` to `https://non-www`

Like:

```
http://example.com               => https://example.com
http://test.example.com          => https://test.example.com
http://api.example.com           => https://api.example.com
http://api.test.example.com      => https://api.test.example.com

http://www.example.com           => https://example.com
http://www.test.example.com      => https://test.example.com
http://www.api.example.com       => https://api.example.com
http://www.api.test.example.com  => https://api.test.example.com

https://www.example.com          => https://example.com
https://www.test.example.com     => https://test.example.com
https://www.api.example.com      => https://api.example.com
https://www.api.test.example.com => https://api.test.example.com
```

Looking at a some simple example I've found online, I tried the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com test.example.com www.example.com www.test.example.com api.example.com api.test.example.com www.api.example.com www.api.test.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com www.test.example.com www.api.example.com www.api.test.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com test.example.com api.example.com api.test.example.com;
    # 
    # The rest of the config that that follows is indeed for the names
    # that I want to redirect everything to
    # ...
}
```

I thought that `$host` means the part of the url before `/` and without `www`.
Like if I access `www.api.test.example.com` then **$host** would be `api.test.example.com`. And so on.

But, after noticing the way it's behaving and checking out Nginx variables, it seems I thought wrong. Although it doesn't explain very clearly and doesn't offer examples, nor do they say what variable to use in order to get the full domain (subdomain included) without www.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this, but if this server only handles subdomains of `example.com`, you can simplify by using regular expressions and default servers, rather than specifying long lists to the `server_name` directive.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name ~^www\.(?<domain>.+)$;

    return 301 https://$domain$request_uri;        
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;        
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ...
}
```

The first `server` block only matches hostnames that begin with `www.`. The second server block matches everything else using `http`. The third `server` block matches everything else using `https`.

It is assumed that this server has a wildcard certificate, common to all subdomains. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! Is it ok if I wrap your `return 301...` in a `location / {}` block? Because I also need to add another location before the redirect: `root /var/www/letsencrypt; location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { default_type "text/plain"; try_files $uri =404; }` I mean I've tried (same for each of the 2 server blocks) and it's working. I'm just not sure if it's ok to repeat myself (I've added it in both server blocks before the redirect)

Comment: Oh, and I don't have a wildcard cert. But I can simply re-generate my cert when adding a new subdomain (it doesn't occur very often and, the way I have my Docker setup, I run one script and it takes less than a minute - of course, I only have a few subdomains now, maybe it wouldn't be that quick with 100, but still on script). Will check Let's Encrypt periodically, they'll offer the wildcard soon (if not already)

Comment: Yes. In fact you must wrap the return within the default location block if you want to add more locations.

Comment: Awesome! Nginx newb here, but I love it! Thanks!